# local minima in the accuracy of a deep neural netowk

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

What suggestion will you give to improve accuracy of a deep neural network with exhibiting local minima in accuracy graph?

[image: Accuracy Graph]

Comment: What's on your horizontal axis?

Comment: jafergas, x axis is number of iterations. I epoch has 12 mini-batches.

Comment: What is your mini-batch size?

Comment: @jafergas, mini batch size is **1024**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are observing are fluctuations in the accuracy of your model during training due to the fact that you are computing gradients with respect to each mini-batch. These are meant to approximate the gradient with respect to the whole training set, but they are not always accurate so sometimes you will observe your accuracy go down.

Some fluctuations can also be due to your loss function not being perfectly correlated with your accuracy metric.

The term "local minimum" is usually used to describe when a loss function has a local minimum that is different from its global minimum. I would not use it here to describe fluctuations the accuracy plot since it might cause confusion. After all you are trying to maximize accuracy.

Comment: Thank you so much Imran.

Comment: You're welcome! If this fully solved your problem please accept my answer